# Why is created_at (customer_entity table) set to change on update?

Tags: magento-1.7

When looking at the structure of the `customer_entity` table, I noticed the `created_at` field has this attribute: `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.  So every time the row is updated, the `created_at` timestamp changes.

It seems like this attribute should exist on the `updated_at` field, not the `created_at` field.  I know it's rare that this table is directly modified due to the EAV structure, but it still seems wrong to ever modify the `created_at` field.

Is there a reason for this table structure, or is it just a bug?

Edit: I found a confirmed bug report from Magento for this.  Issue #27944.  Unfortunately, you must log in to view it.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=13882

Comment: Good question. I might add that these tables are in the same situation:`cron_schedule`, `api_user`, `admin_user`, `customer_entity_address`, `downloadable_link_purchased`, `downloadable_link_purchased_item`, `index_event`, `eav_entity` `log_customer`, `sales_flat_quote_address`, `sales_flat_quote`, `sales_flat_quote_address_item`, `sales_flat_quote_payment`, `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate`, `sales_recurring_profile`. There might be others also. I kind of lost interest at one point, while searching for them.

Comment: I noticed `sales_flat_quote` first, then checked `customer_entity`.  We just noticed it because some of our reports weren't making any sense.  Can this really be a bug?

Comment: I believe it is just a bug.

Comment: I there any way we can work around that?
Sorry I am a newbie and am facing the same issue since i upgraded from 1.7.0.2 to 1.8.1
I am almost afraid to try editing the field in the database. Hope you can help!! Thanks Jinal

Comment: @Jinal, your best option is to make the changes via mysql.  Check Marius's answer for more details, and make sure to backup your database first!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is what I found. The problem appears only on Magento CE 1.6+ (and matching EE versions). It's because of the new install/upgrade scripts using DDL in combination with mysql.
In versions before 1.6 this is how the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns looked like:

```
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
```

In 1.6+ the ddl looks like this:

```
    ->addColumn('created_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Created At')
    ->addColumn('updated_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Updated At')
```

and generates:

```
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL COMMENT 'Created At',
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL COMMENT 'Updated At',
```

The difference is that the `default` value is missing.
And, as [described here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html),

> With neither DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP nor ON UPDATE
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, it is the same as specifying both DEFAULT
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

And since MySQL allows only one timestamp column with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default or for `on update`, the `created_at` column ends up with like this.

This is definitely a Magento bug .

Comment: has there been any update from magento on this? it seems the bug is still in the new state.

Comment: @Laura, the bug tracking link in the answer still shows as open (almost 2 years now!).

Comment: In Magento 1.9, the created_at column says: `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Created At'. And in release notes, it's mentioned that "The "customer since" date is correct."

Comment: For EE it's affecting versions BEFORE 1.6, I have EE 1.13 and it looks like this:  
`\`created_at\` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Created At'`

Answer (score 4):

First of all, read Marius' answer to see what's happening in the database.

I just wanted to mention that most developers won't run into this problem if their model properly extends `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`. The stack looks like this:

1. `Your_Model::save` calls
2. `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::save` calls
3. `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::save` calls
4. `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::_beforeSave` calls
5. `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::walkAttributes` calls
6. `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Time_Created::beforeSave`

This does the following:

```
$attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
$date = $object->getData($attributeCode);
if (is_null($date)) {
    if ($object->isObjectNew()) {
        $object->setData($attributeCode, Varien_Date::now());
    }
}
```

Just note that this can have [problems](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18062/customer-created-at-date-off-by-months/31225#31225) for some locales in both CE >= 1.8.x and EE >= 1.13.x.

Answer (score 2):

We, too, found this bug, and think that it's based on the difference between US and European date encoding.

In the United States, dates are written MM-DD-YYYY. (02-10-2015 = Feb 10, 2015). But in Europe and many other places, dates are written DD-MM-YYYY.  (02-10-2015 = 2nd October 2015, or Oct 2, 2015).

While Magento is based in the US, much of the development was done by programmers in the Ukraine.

We have fixed this bug with a free Magento extension (so that you don't have to change any Magento Core Code).  We have put it up on our site as a free download:
http://www.CustomerParadigm.com/download/Magento-Date-Switch-Fix-Extension.zip

I've covered this in more detail on our blog here:
http://www.customerparadigm.com/magento-bug-magento-customer-create-date-juxtaposition/

Comment: Blog post and module are just pulled from my SE post here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/31225

Answer (score -1):

ce 1.9 have fix the bug in ce 1.8.1
Below is the diff:
[image]

Comment: The new code here isn't a fix for this issue. It just validates a "DDDD-DD-DD DD:DD:DD" format, or returns null. That null will still hit the database and become whatever the columns default value is.