# Customer created_at Date off by months

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.8.1.0, date

I'm working on syncing my customers with a third party application and have discovered that many of my `created_at` dates are way off.

Today is `2014-04-08` yet I have several records with a created_at date in the future - `2014-06-01`, `2014-06-03`, `2014-05-06`...

I'm not exactly sure where to start troubleshooting.

[This](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16176/magento-1-8-1-updates-customer-created-at-time-on-every-save) question touches on the issue, but it (and it's duplicate) are both more related to the multiple updates. I'm not seeing the created_at date changing on save/update, but I am having the date be off by days or months.

I poked around the `/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Backend/Time/Created.php` and `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php` files but didn't see anything obviously wrong.

Does anyone have any advice about how to have accurate created_at dates? Should I comment out code similar to @alex's solution?

I'm using Magento 1.8.1.0

Timezone is CST - America/Chicago

Locale: English (United States)

Answer (score 8):

The problem is in `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Time_Created::beforeSave`. This line ends up swapping the month and day:

```
$zendDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->utcDate(null, $date, true, $this->_getFormat($date));
```

This happens to just about all entity types including products and customers, and happens during creation and normal save events, in both CE >= 1.8.x and EE >= 1.13.x.

[Override this model in your own module](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/), and replace the `beforeSave` method with this:

```
public function beforeSave($object)
{
    $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
    $date = $object->getData($attributeCode);
    if (is_null($date)) {
        if ($object->isObjectNew()) {
            $object->setData($attributeCode, Varien_Date::now());
        }
    } else {
        // ADD THIS
        $date = strtotime($date);

        // convert to UTC
        $zendDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->utcDate(null, $date, true, $this->_getFormat($date));
        $object->setData($attributeCode, $zendDate->getIso());
    }

    return $this;
}
```

This also needs to be corrected on the way out of the database. Replace `afterLoad` with this:

```
public function afterLoad($object)
{
    $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
    $date = $object->getData($attributeCode);

    // ADD THIS
    if (!is_null($date)) {
        $date = strtotime($date);
    }

    $zendDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeDate(null, $date, true, $this->_getFormat($date));
    $object->setData($attributeCode, $zendDate->getIso());

    parent::afterLoad($object);

    return $this;
}
```

**Edit:** Here is an example of how to override this class.

```
<global>
    <models>
        <eav>
            <rewrite>
                <entity_attribute_backend_time_created>Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Time_Created</entity_attribute_backend_time_created>
            </rewrite>
        </eav>
    </models>
</global>
```

Then create the file `app\code\local\Mycompany\Mymodule\Model\Eav\Entity\Attribute\Backend\Time\Created.php`

Comment: How to map the above model in the config.xml file. When I do the mapping I'm getting an error saying Invalid backend model specified: eav/entity_attribute_backend_time_created"

Comment: @sutha Please see my edit.

Comment: it should be 
app\code\local\Mycompany\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\Time\Created.php
<global>
    <models>
        <eav>
            <rewrite>
                <entity_attribute_backend_time_created>Mycompany_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Time_Created</entity_attribute_backend_time_created>
            </rewrite>
        </eav>
    </models>
</global>

Comment: If you mirror Mage in app/code/local, you dont need to add the config as mentioned

Comment: @prashant That's true, but then you would need to copy the entire class, and that makes upgrading Magento more tedious later. Always use event observers if possible, extending models if not, and only replace the whole class as a last resort.

Comment: @TylerV. Your comment brings me to a question. How would you decide the order in which an event-observer must trigger. For instance, there could be something required to happen before a another event is called. In other words, how to assign priority?

Answer (score 0):

I also seen that in Magento EE 1.14.2.0 have issue of created date with admin user and api user, whenever we are updating admin user or api user its created date changed by current date and time. I checked and found that in database it default value was **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** , to resolve this issue make a sql file in your module and use below query to change default value

**For Admin User**

ALTER TABLE `admin_user` 
CHANGE COLUMN `created` `created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'User Created Time' ;

**For API User**

ALTER TABLE `api_user` 
CHANGE COLUMN `created` `created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'User record create date' ;