# Magento 1.9 Wrong customer created and last login dates

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, customer, date

I am running Magento v.1.9.0.1 and I am facing a problem with the dates displayed when editing a customer via the admin area. For example,

Last Logged In: **11 Feb 7791** 4:23:48 μ.μ.
Last Logged In (Europe/Istanbul):   **09 Feb 2015** 3:16:31 μ.μ.
Account Created on: **02 Sep 2015** 4:16:11 μ.μ.

The client registered on the 9th of February 2015. I searched around and found topics about other Magento versions that said for some dates Magento is swapping the dates, hence the difference between actual created date (09/02/2015) and reported created date (02/09/2015).

I couldn't find anything about version 1.9 nor anything about the year reported for last logged in (7791!).

Is there a fix for this problem?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Answer to your problem is here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18062/customer-created-at-date-off-by-months?lq=1