# Created date is wrong in customer grid tried the available solution but not solved

Tags: magento-1.8, customer

I have tried the solution like [Customer created_at Date off by months](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18062/customer-created-at-date-off-by-months)

when I use it it gives me error like

> > Call to undefined method
> >     Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Time_Created::_getFormat(
> >     )

even I have override by placing the `created.php` file in `app/code/local/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Backend/Time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_getFormat()` method is not available in `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Time_Created` by default. I dont know, but I believe may be @Taylor is wrong in the usage of the function `_getFormat()`.

***[The correct formatted code is now available from Magento version 1.8.1.0](https://github.com/speedupmate/Magento-CE-Mirror/blob/e113f5be413f7e28253d9ac9aced3422ca88b491/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Backend/Time/Created.php)***. This is not included in default Magento 1.8.0.0 or lower versions. So use that file instead of your default `Created.php`.

---

***Note :*** When you override via `local` pool, make sure the file name is `Created.php` and not `created.php`. As Taylor pointed out in his answer, it is not a good practice to rewrite via `local` codepool. Instead use a module rewrite.

Comment: My file name is allready Created.php. I got the same error when i have override it to my custom module.

Comment: replace file content with the content in the link that I have provided and then check again

Comment: I found the solution , placed the function protected function _getFormat($date)
    {
        if (is_string($date) && preg_match('#^\d{4,4}-\d{2,2}-\d{2,2} \d{2,2}:\d{2,2}:\d{2,2}$#', $date)) {
            return 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss';
        }
        return null;
    }   and works fine