# 1.9.0.1 community version incorrect user registration date

Tags: magento-1.9

The date in customer view grid is invalid. it switches month with date and displays vice versa e.g, a user who registered on `Jan 12, 2016 10:58:25 AM` is displayed as `Dec 1, 2016 11:44:37 AM` as create date.

Comment: Check the answer of this post: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18062/customer-created-at-date-off-by-months

Answer (score 0):

I tried different answers from this forum and other forums as well. This has been resolved. I created the Create.php file in local custom module and commented out the below code altogether. the utcDate function was creating the issue. even if everything was perfectly set

```
 $zendDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->utcDate(null, $date, true);
 $object->setData($attributeCode, $zendDate->getIso());
```